# Does any scripture describe Chitragupta as a god?

Tags: scripture, gods, chitragupta

I know that Chitragupta is Lord Yama's assisant and also worshipped in some places in South India. But, do any scriptures state that he is a deity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes Chitragupta is described as deity in scriptures:

> सौम्ये गुरुर्बुधश्चैशे शुक्रः पूर्वदले शशी ॥१६७.००२
> आग्नेये दक्षिणे भौमो मध्ये स्याद्भास्करस्तथा ।१६७.००३
> शनिराप्येऽथ नैर्ऋत्ये राहुः केतुश्च वायवे ॥१६७.००३
> ईशश्चोमा गुहो विष्णुर्ब्रह्मेन्द्रौ यमकालकौ ।१६७.००४
> **चित्रगुप्तश्चाधिदेवा** अग्निरापः क्षितिर्हरिः ॥१६७.००४ (Agni Purana) 
>  
> After having invoked planets in a circle at the north-east of the fire-pit with the sacred syllables, Jupiter (should be located) at the north, Mercury at the northeast, Venus at the east, Moon at the south-east, Mars at the south and the Sun in the middle. Saturn (should be located) at the west, Rāhu, the ascending node at the south-west and Ketu, the descending node at the north-west. Īśa (lord Shiva), Umā, Guha, Viṣṇu, Brahmā, Indra, Yama, Kālaka and **Chitragupta** are the presiding **deities.**

[This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423580.html) of Skanda Purana also describes misery befallen due to not worshipping Chitragupta:

> During the Citrā constellation in the month of Caitra, O my beloved one, sweet drinks, jackfruīt and tasty plantains were not given by me to Vedic scholars. Similarly an umbrella, a walking stick, a beautiful pair of sandals, betel leaves, flowers, sandal-paste and unguents were not given by me to them **for the propitiation of Citragupta**. It is on account of the sin thereof that this misery has befallen me.