# Who is Kalaka, and is there any other information about Mahesha, Sarada, and Vaitala?

Tags: shiva, avatars, shiva-purana, reference-request

In the answer to [my question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55938/does-any-scripture-describe-chitragupta-as-a-god/55939#55939), I learned about the name 'Kalaka'. But, who *is* Kalaka?

---

I found some background behind Shiva, Parvati, and Bhairava's incarnations, Mahesha, Sarada and Vaitala in this chapter of [Shiva Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226417.html). Is there any other information about them in any scriptures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kalaka is a powerful Gaṇa. (A gaṇa is a deity associated with Lords Shiva and Ganesha; they live at Kailasa.)

---

Shiva Purana [2.2.33](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226053.html) says:

> 23. O sage, Kuṇḍī **the most excellent of the Gaṇas** and Parvataka went each with twelve crores in order to destroy Dakṣa’s sacrifice:
> 24. Kāla, **Kālaka** and Mahākāla went to the sacrifice of Dakṣa with a hundred crores.

and [2.1.20](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226018.html) says:

> 15-16. Viṣṭambha and Candratāpana each with eight crores, the leader of Gaṇas Mahākeśa with a thousand crores.
>
> 7. Kuṇḍin, Vāha and the auspicious Parvataka with twelve crores each, Kāla, **Kālaka** and Mahākāla each with a hundred crores.
> 8. Agnika with a hundred crores, Abhimukha with a crore, Ādityamūrdhā and Dhanāvaha each with a crore.
> 9. Sannāha and Kumuda with a hundred crores, Amogha, Kokila and Sumantraka each with a crore.

---

Your Shiva Purana story seems to be the only place where Mahesha, Sarada, and Vaitala are mentioned, though a line in the same Purana treats 'Mahesa' as another name for Shiva. Otherwise, these avatars are never again mentioned.

> Obeisance to Thee, O lord, from whom the mobile and the immobile beings have originated. Obeisance to the great Puruṣa, **Maheśa**, the supreme Īśa and the great Ātman. [[2.2.15]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226035.html)

Comment: @Boovanaes - I will try!

Comment: @Boovanaes - I couldn't find any authentic scriptural stories to answer that question. The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harihara) article about Harihara has one interesting story, but it is a 'legend,' not from the canon.